# android code function

Tags: android

I don't understand what string return this part of code and what it do:

```
.method public static getDv()Ljava/lang/String;
.locals 4

.prologue
sget-object v2, Lit/myappfolder/android/myapp/Database;->context:Landroid/content/Context;

const-string v3, "phone"

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Landroid/content/Context;->getSystemService(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v0

check-cast v0, Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getDeviceId()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

return-object v1
```

.end method

Can you tell me what?
Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wil return the device ID of the phone, using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) method. For future reference, this is dalvik bytecode.